# Most recent original Marvel and DC hero?

Tags: marvel, comics, dc

I know Marvel and DC have well established characters, so they rarely need to create original ones. I want to know the last original hero for each universe as of August 2015.

This does not count a different person being the same hero (like a different Spider-Man or Robin is still that hero, just a different person).

Answer (score 2):

### Marvel

- [Ms. Marvel (Kamala Khan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms._Marvel_(Kamala_Khan)) debuted in 2013
- [Silk](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f1/Silk-comic_cover.jpg/250px-Silk-comic_cover.jpg) debuted in 2014

That being said, both are strongly connected to prior heroes from the same stable.

The most recent *wholly-new creation* seems to be [**Blue Marvel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Marvel_(Marvel_Comics)) (2008)

[image: Blue Marvel on the right clashes and fights with King Hyperion on the left; both are running at each other punching and are near symmetrical]

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [List of Superhero debuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_superhero_debuts) may be helpful, although it's certainly not going to be comprehensive.

- DC introduced [King Chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Chimera) in April 2009 (JSA #24)
- Marvel introduced [Lyra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She-Hulk_(Lyra)) in August 2008.